# UWP Push Notification - Send message externally

Tags: push-notification, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have Register my app for the windows store (by doing steps 1 to 13) as in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification#register-your-app-for-the-windows-store)

Now notification works when I'am adding notifications in developer account. Now I want to know that can I send the notification message to my app externally? For example when I enter a text on html/php page and press a button, that entered text should be send as a notification message to all app users (both foreground and background). How can I link all this?

Answer (score 1):

if you registered your app to get a push notification channel your getting an uri where you can reach your app. In your php script you need to send notifications to that uri. So your app have to register the uri in your backend so you have it available in your sender. then when you push the button you need to send the notification to that uri. see more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview

Comment: I have got a unique identifier and secret key. Is there any useful link for sending notiification using php and uri ?

Comment: this? http://phpwebschool.com/send-windows-push-notification-services-wns-using-php/

Comment: In WNS we see there is an option for sending notification to all users. without depending on uri. is it possible using php?

Comment: where do you see that? i think you looking at notification hub; not WNS

Comment: on developer account -> Dashboard ->  engage  ->  notifications

Comment: that is just from dev center to engage users. no api to use that

Comment: ohh ok. I got https://arjunkr.quora.com/How-to-Windows-10-WNS-Windows-Notification-Service-via-PHP   this link for sending messages using php. But how can  I receive it in windows10 end?